# Помогите написать аналог кода XAML на C# (нужно динамично создавать и затирать IMAGE)

Tags: c#, wpf

Помогите изобразить аналог ниже изложенного кода XAML в виде C#. Проблема с сборщиком мусора. При смене source для этого Image - предыдущее изображение из памяти не затирается (для меня это критично в связи с большим объемом), затирается только третье по счету. Помогает только imageCanv.Children.Clear - но при этом нужно заново создавать Image на этом холсте.

```
<Canvas Name="imageCanv" MouseRightButtonDown="imageCanv_MouseRightButtonDown">
                    <Image Name="a52" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="1">
                        <Image.LayoutTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform x:Name="scale"/>
                        </Image.LayoutTransform>
                    </Image>  
                </Canvas>
```

P.S. Что примечательно, если поставить
перед сменой изображения "мэсэджБокс"
то мусорщик затирает нормально. Не
могу понять этого явления - может
из-за остановки потока мусорщик делает
свои "дела" более тщательно.

Comment: Насколько знаю, у wpf с этим вообще проблемы. Здесь целая статья об этом и способах решния, но я ее так и не осилил: http://habrahabr.ru/post/164543/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо, вам нужно вот что:

```
var image = new Image();
Canvas.SetLeft(image, 0);
Canvas.SetTop(image, 1);
var transform = new ScaleTransform();
image.LayoutTransform = transform;
```

ЗЫ: У меня как-то была похожая проблема. Я бы посоветовал memory profiler, чтобы в точности разобраться, где, кто и на что держит ссылки. Угадать методом "пристального взгляда" практически невозможно.

Comment: Похоже на то. Послезавтра попробую. На форумах наших иностранных коллег еще рекомендуют использовать streamsource вместо urisource.